# How to create a column that is dependent on several events over time with a certain threshold?

Tags: r, dplyr

In the data below we observe an indexed GDP rate of a certain country over time. My aim is to create a binary variable: 0= no crisis, 1= crisis. If the index is below the past 5 year average, then the variable is coded as 1=crisis until it reaches back the initial 5 year average.

In the example below, the GDP average between 1990 and 1994 is 98. In 1995, the GDP was 96 and hence the variable is coded as 1 until it went up to 99 (beyond the level of 98) in 1999. This scenario happened again between 2002 and 2005 until the GDP level goes back above the 5 year average level of 101.6 of the years 1997 to 2001. Can someone help with this please?

```
GDP year Expected output
100 1990    0
99  1991    0
98  1992    0
97  1993    0
98  1994    0
96  1995    1
94  1996    1
95  1997    1
97  1998    1
99  1999    0
110 2000    0
107 2001    0
100 2002    1
98  2003    1
99  2004    1
97  2005    1
102 2006    0
103 2007    0
102 2008    0
```

Here is the data:

```
df= structure(list(`Index 100` = c(100, 99, 98, 97, 98, 96, 94, 95, 
97, 99, 110, 107, 100, 98, 99, 97, 102, 103, 102), year = c(1990, 
1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 
2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008), `Expected output` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-19L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use slider's `slide_dbl` to get the `mean` of the prior 5 years per below:

A few notes:

1. Without `.complete = TRUE`, it would calculate a mean for partial windows.
2. If your real dataset has multiple countries, then don't forget to `group_by(country) |>` first.
3. You could consider using janitor's `clean_names` to ensure the variable names are syntactic, e.g. would not then need backticks.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(slider)

# Sample data
df <- structure(list(`Index 100` = c(
  100, 99, 98, 97, 98, 96, 94, 95,
  97, 99, 110, 107, 100, 98, 99, 97, 102, 103, 102
), year = c(
  1990,
  1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001,
  2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008
), `Expected output` = c(
  0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0
)), row.names = c(
  NA,
  -19L
), class = "data.frame")

# Code
df |>
  arrange(year) |>
  mutate(
    sliding_mean = slide_dbl(lag(`Index 100`), mean, .before = 4, .complete = TRUE),
    crisis = case_when(
      `Index 100` < sliding_mean ~ 1,
      `Index 100` >= sliding_mean & `Index 100` < first(na.omit(sliding_mean)) ~ 1,
      TRUE ~ 0
    )
  )
#>    Index 100 year Expected output sliding_mean crisis
#> 1        100 1990               0           NA      0
#> 2         99 1991               0           NA      0
#> 3         98 1992               0           NA      0
#> 4         97 1993               0           NA      0
#> 5         98 1994               0           NA      0
#> 6         96 1995               1         98.4      1
#> 7         94 1996               1         97.6      1
#> 8         95 1997               1         96.6      1
#> 9         97 1998               1         96.0      1
#> 10        99 1999               0         96.0      0
#> 11       110 2000               0         96.2      0
#> 12       107 2001               0         99.0      0
#> 13       100 2002               1        101.6      1
#> 14        98 2003               1        102.6      1
#> 15        99 2004               1        102.8      1
#> 16        97 2005               1        102.8      1
#> 17       102 2006               0        100.2      0
#> 18       103 2007               0         99.2      0
#> 19       102 2008               0         99.8      0

# Check
(100+99+98+97+98)/5
#> [1] 98.4
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I was wondering why it gives a different result in 1998? The GDP in that year is 97 still below the 5 year average (of 1990 to 1994) which is 98. So this should be considered a crisis year

Comment: I am sorry to bother again. With the helpful code you suggested the year of the observation counts in the moving average, on top of the other previous 5 years. Is there a way to create the average of the only previous 5 years?

Comment: Inside the slide_dbl try wrapping the Index 100 including the backticks in lag(), and set .before to 4.

Comment: I tried it but it is not working, would it be possible to include it in your code please?

Comment: Included per above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
library(dplyr)

df |> mutate(crisis = case_when(lag(c( rep(0 , 4),
zoo::rollmean(df$GDP , 5)),1)> GDP ~ 1 , TRUE ~ 0))
```

- output

```
   GDP year crisis
1  100 1990      0
2   99 1991      0
3   98 1992      0
4   97 1993      0
5   98 1994      0
6   96 1995      1
7   94 1996      1
8   95 1997      1
9   97 1998      0
10  99 1999      0
11 110 2000      0
12 107 2001      0
13 100 2002      1
14  98 2003      1
15  99 2004      1
16  97 2005      1
17 102 2006      0
18 103 2007      0
19 102 2008      0
```

- output to improve understanding about the solution

```
   GDP year crisis Five_years_avg
1  100 1990      0             NA
2   99 1991      0            0.0
3   98 1992      0            0.0
4   97 1993      0            0.0
5   98 1994      0            0.0
6   96 1995      1           98.4
7   94 1996      1           97.6
8   95 1997      1           96.6
9   97 1998      0           96.0
10  99 1999      0           96.0
11 110 2000      0           96.2
12 107 2001      0           99.0
13 100 2002      1          101.6
14  98 2003      1          102.6
15  99 2004      1          102.8
16  97 2005      1          102.8
17 102 2006      0          100.2
18 103 2007      0           99.2
19 102 2008      0           99.8
```

in 1998 GDP is 97 and the average of the past 5 years was 96 so the is no crisis.

Comment: I was wondering why it gives a different result in 1998? The GDP in that year is 97 still below the 5 year average (of 1990 to 1994) which is 98. So this should be considered a crisis year

Comment: Do you mean you want compare all GDP's  with the average of the first five years which is 98? or the average of past 5 years from GDP?

Comment: I want to compare the GDP of each year with the average GDP of the last 5 years. Once there is an event that shows that the GDP is below the previous five-year average as it occurs in the year 1995 because the GDP is 96 below the 5-year average (1990-1994) of 98, only when a GDP in any subsequent year is above 98 then the crisis is over and we coded the variable as 0. However, in the helpful code you provided, the GDP in year 1998 is 97, still below the 5 year average of GDP 98, and the crisis is coded as 0 but should be coded as 1 that year